# C++ и API OpenMP переменная среды

Tags: c++, api, openmp

начал изучать параллельное программирование, подключил API OpenMP в проект C++. Добавлением кода

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fopenmp")
```

в файл CMakeLists.txt
Далее пытался изменить значение переменной OMP_NUM_THREADS через export, а именно

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
export OMP_NUM_THREADS = 15; 
int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Но программа выдаёт ошибку, не могли бы вы подсказать с чем это связано? Знаю, что можно ещё 2-мя другими способами, через опцию num_threads и функцию omp_set_num_threads, но необходимо сделать именно так.
Ошибку выкидывает следующую:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Lab1.dir/main.cpp.obj
C:\Users\Home\Desktop\ParallelProgramming\Lab1\Lab1\main.cpp:3:1: warning: keyword 'export' not implemented, and will be ignored
 export OMP_NUM_THREADS = 15;
 ^~~~~~
C:\Users\Home\Desktop\ParallelProgramming\Lab1\Lab1\main.cpp:3:8: error: 'OMP_NUM_THREADS' does not name a type
 export OMP_NUM_THREADS = 15;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Среда для разработки используется следующая JetBrains CLion 2018.2.3

Comment: По-моему это делается через детективы, вариант с экспорт вижу первый раз, используйте стандартные детективы `#pragma omp ...`

Comment: На сайте IBM нашел статейку, где используют export. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ru/SSGH2K_13.1.3/com.ibm.xlc1313.aix.doc/compiler_ref/ruomprun4.html

Comment: но только вот всё-же не работает

Comment: Возможно вам нужно именно OMP, но на всякий случай напишу, что Intel TBB значительно более красивая, понятная и с куда большими возможностями бибилиотека

Comment: Версию компилятора назовите пожалуйста. Разные компиляторы поддерживают разные версии openMP + *программа выдаёт ошибку* - неинформативное описание проблемы

Comment: Там же (в статейке) ясно написано, что этот способ только для компилятора IBM  XL C для компьютеров с  IBM AIX. Это нестандартный способ задания переменных окружения и вряд ли он будет работать с другими компиляторами C/C++. Эту переменную принято задавать до запуска Вашей программы ручками или скриптом. Либо используйте системные вызовы для установки переменной окружения, если очень надо делать это изнутри программы. Но... изнутри программы лучше воспользоваться той самой функцией.

Comment: А как сделать системный вызов? У меня просто задание сделать через переменную окружения...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от операционной системы, Вы можете использовать либо системный вызов [`putenv()`](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/spr/332.php) для POSIX (юниксоподобных) систем с *устаревшими* системами/компиляторами, либо [`setenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setenv.html#tag_03_647_08) с более новыми, либо [`_putenv()`, `_wputenv()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/putenv-wputenv) (или безопасные аналоги последних: [`_putenv_s()`, `_wputenv_s()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/putenv-s-wputenv-s)) для MS Windows.

Но скорее всего, в задании подразумевалось установить переменную окружения до старта Вашей программы. Например, если Вы работаете в *bash* под *Linux*, то можно для запуска программы в шелл сначала выполнить команду `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=15`, а уже после этого запускать саму программу. Ну, или можно сделать скрипт из пары этих строк.

Comment: В задании нет точного описания, к сожалению... мне нужно до запуска метода main я так понимаю изменить значение переменной OMP_NUM_THREADS, чтобы код вывел несколько раз Hello World!\n работаю в Windows компилятор JetBrains CLion 2018.2.3

Comment: В Windows, да еще и до запуска main() у Вас нет больше никаких вариантов, кроме установки переменной окружения в командной строке или в скрипте запуска. В Windows для этого используется команда `set`, например: `set OMP_NUM_THREADS=15`